# How to pass data from callback function to MainPage(another class) in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

There are two class MainPage and Callback. I used C++ library, so I get byte array via CLI. When I get data callback class, I want pass the data callback class to MainPage class(It's UI thread). Finally, I want to draw Image after getting byte array.

---

```
<Image x:Name="ImageScreen" x:FieldModifier="public" Height="357" Width="456" Margin="0,33,0,201"/>
```

== MainPage.xaml.cs ==

```
public class Callback : ComponentCallback
{
    static byte[] byteArray;        
    ...
    // I get data via this function. When I get the data,
    // I want to pass the data to updateImage function in MainPage class.
    public void onFrameLoaded(int camera, String title, UInt32 bufferSize)
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.List<byte> buffer = MainPage._watcher.getBuffer().ToList();

        byteArray = buffer.ToArray();

        // I want pass byteArray to updateImage.
    }
}    

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public static Component _watcher;
    public static Callback _watcherCallback;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CoreComponent _core = new CoreComponent();
        int fenport = _core.fenServerPort();
        _core.setFenServer("", );
        fenport = _core.fenServerPort();

        _watcher = new Component();
        _watcherCallback = new Callback();
        _watcher.setCallback(_watcherCallback);
        _watcher.connect(0, "", 0, "", "");            
    }        

    public void updateImage(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        bi.SetSource(stream);

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            //Update the UI controls here
            ImageScreen.Source = bi;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var frame = Window.Current as Frame;

if (frame == null)
{
    return; //?
}

var mainPage = frame.Content as MainPage;

if (mainPage == null)
{
    return; //?
}

mainPage.updateImage(byteArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. However I don't know that Where can I write this sentence. [var frame = Window.Current as Frame;]

Comment: This sentence(Window.Current) makes some errors. I think it can be used on a window 8, not on windows phone 8.

Comment: the name 'windows' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Not "windows" - `Window`. As in [Windows.UI.Xaml.Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.aspx).

Comment: Oh, right, I missed that you are on the phone, though that should still work I think. Typical error might be caused if you are on the wrong thread - then you'd need to store a reference to the current UI dispatcher object when you start the app and invoke these calls on the dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Thanks for your help Filip.

```
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            PhoneApplicationFrame frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;

            if (frame == null) {
                return; //?
            }

            var mainPage = frame.Content as MainPage;

            if (mainPage == null) {
                return; //?
            }

            mainPage.updateImage(byteArray);
        });
```